# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined when submitting array values from form in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a form with array values in this array format since I don't know how to dynamically add form inputs, I had to manually do it. Now when I tried submitting the form, this error got display **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined**

**post.html**

```
     <ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
        <ion-input type="text" readonly  name="party" placeholder="APC"  value="apc"></ion-input>
        <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" #vote></ion-input>

    </ion-item>

    <ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
        <ion-input type="text" readonly name="party"  value="pdp"></ion-input>
      <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" #vote></ion-input>
       </ion-item>

<ion-item class="mylist chat-item item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right list card animated fadeInUp">
<ion-input type="text" readonly  name="party"  value="apga"></ion-input>  
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" #vote></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**post.ts**

```
@ViewChild("party") party;
@ViewChild("vote") vote; 

@ViewChild("phones")phones; 


submit(){
let data = {
            party: this.party.value,
            vote:   this.vote.value, 
            phone:   this.phones.value

          };

}
```

Please how can I pass these array values?

Thanks

Comment: @Swapnil Patwa, pls I need your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngModel`.

**post.html**

```
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="Total Votes" name="vote" [(ngModel)]="party"></ion-input>
```

**post.ts**

```
 export class Post {
  party;

  constructor() {}

  submit(){
    let data = { 
      party: this.party };
      }
    }
```

[check this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nkz7v5?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: @Sunarshana Pradeep, do you mean party: any; cause just party; gives error

Comment: @TonyeBoro, this should work. I created an example for you. check example link in the answer.

Comment: @Sunarshana Pradeep, do you mean party: any; cause just party; gives error

Comment: @TonyeBoro, you can use any or some other type. See my example in the link. its working.